# Resources for Basic Unix System Administration (OSX)

Tags: documentation, system-administration

After, reading and understanding Dan Benjamin's post about [installing Ruby, Rails, etc. on OSX (Leopard)](http://hivelogic.com/articles/2008/02/ruby-rails-leopard), I really jumped at using `usr/local`, maybe at my peril and without understanding it fully. I've had no problem running Rails on my local machine, but I still feel like I don't quite wrap my head around these basic sysadmin practices.

As an example, when I run `which git` the path my git installation is running from is `/usr/local/git/bin/git` -- does that seem *right?*

I've learned the bulk of my programming thanks to JavaScript, and I haven't really had to go deeply under the hood of the Mac, but I'm very anxious to use these command line tools and scripts.

Can you recommend a good resource for documentation on basic Unix system administration for beginners (preferably for the Mac-set)?

I realize this might not be totally programming related, but I believe basic shell and command-line scripting knowledge is pretty crucial and I'd like to feel confident moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For improving your basic shell and command-line scripting knowledge, you don't need to get into sysadmin tasks. The nearest source of information (though not the most friendly at first) is the `man` command. Try `man bash` or `man intro`. Start by writing small shell script utilities.

About your question on `git` installation, you can install anything anywhere. But recommended directories are `/usr/local/bin` and `/opt/bin` for system-wide tools and `~/bin` for your private tools. Usually tools create their own subdirectory in recommended directories where they put doc and resources, such as your `/usr/local/git`.

For online resources, I assume that you already know how to find the Apple web site and how to use Google.